# Storing videos from iOS app in icloud account

Tags: ios, video, icloud, icloud-api

I am working on app where the app can take videos from camera and save it locally. If the same videos needs to be made available in other device, then I should go for web service where videos will be stored and accessed from different devices.

I come to know that icloud gives user 5GB of user space, I want to know is there a way for the iOS app to backup the videos from the app and place it in icloud and sync the same videos from different device?

Thanks

Comment: that's iCloud's Photo Stream

Comment: @Raptor: You mean to say that videos will be available both in my app and photos app? Can you explain more in detail as I am new to icloud.

Comment: Should I need to use UIDocument to represent the video file?

Comment: did u worked? i am searching same thing

Comment: @QualityCoder: Yes I am able to achieve this.